# Getting newest docs from CouchDB when looking by multiple keys

Tags: couchdb

I need to get documents from CouchDB by looking in a view with multiple keys, e.g. `keys=["key1", "key2","key3"]`.
Documents look like this:

```
{
   "_id": "142410131701",
   "_rev": "1-6cac8838a4dfc2308f9d06001a899f50", 
   "s": [
       "key1", "key2", "key3"
   ]
}
```

This works fine.
The problem I am facing is how to get the newest docs in the DB? My document _id is actually an Unix Epoch, but I cannot figure out how to get the results ordered by id.
It looks like CouchDB returns the first results in the btree that match key1, then those that match key2, etc., but the newest docs are not the first returned. 
Trying to add the _id to the keys also didn't work.

I have solved the issue for now with a List function that sorts the results by _id, but I wonder if there is a more simple and effective solution.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you added the `_id` to the keys it would have to work (of course, you would have to add it as the first parameter of the key array, which apparently would render this view useless in your case).

But, if you want an automatic view that already indexes the documents by `_id` and sorts them, in your case, from older to newer, it is the `_all_docs` endpoint, which works like a view.

The answer to your question is:

```
curl http://couch.db.com/database/_all_docs?descending=true&include_docs=true&limit=15
```

This will give you the 15 newest docs, in a response more-or-less like the following:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
       "key": "the-id",
       "id": "the-id",
       "value": {"rev": "the-rev"},
       "doc": {
         "your-document": "goes here"
       }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: As I said, I need the results filtered, not all documents. The problem is that the view is sorted only by the first key, not by the second one. But as I need to use starkey and endkey to filter by 's', I cannot reverse the order and put the id first.